# Is spliting tasks into multiple scripts more efficient than a single script? (PHP)

Tags: php, server, ram

Basically, I have a page which loads 5 iframes every 5 seconds, and each iframe references a php script. This works just fine.

Now, the multiple iframes approach doesn't quite cut it anymore because I need everything to load on a single table, so I decided to "merge" the 5 scripts into just one, but taking this approach, the page crashes sometimes, seems like the script uses too much memory (it only uses like 260mb tops).

The same tasks are being performed at the same time, so why does it crash when i do it in a single script?

My question then is: Is spliting tasks into multiple PHP scripts more memory efficient than a single script?

Comment: Yes, because php is single thread

Comment: Personally, Id set up a script that uses multicurl to call and execute each of the 5 scripts simultaneously and wait for all 5 to return, aggregate the data then return that. [See this practical example](https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/)

Comment: It's not that splitting them makes it more _efficient_ per se (in fact, doing that may use more total memory), but to illya's point, there is a memory limit that is being applied to _each request_, and you are hitting that limit when you combine all the tasks into a single request.